# VB.NET SQL Server Insert - ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: sql, vb.net, executenonquery

In the form load event, I connect to the SQL Server database:

```
Private Sub AddBook_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            myConnection = New SqlConnection("server=.\SQLEXPRESS;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=CIEDC")
            myConnection.Open()

End Sub
```

Here in the Insert event, I use the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click
            Try
                myConnection.Open()
                myCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblBook(BookCode, BookTitle, Author, PublishingYear, Price, EnterDate, CatID, RackID, Amount) VALUES('" & txtBookCode.Text & "','" & txtTitle.Text & "','" & txtAuthor.Text & "','" & txtPublishYear.Text & "','" & txtPrice.Text & "', #" & txtEnterDate.Text & "#, " & txtCategory.Text & "," & txtRack.Text & "," & txtAmount.Text & ")")
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("The book named '" & txtTitle.Text & "' has been inseted successfully")
                ClearBox()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message())
            End Try
            myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

And It produces the following error:

```
ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 8):

1. **Connection Assignment** - You aren't setting the connection property of the SQLCommand. You can do this without adding a line of code. *This is the cause of your error.*

   ```
   myCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblBook(BookCode, BookTitle, Author, PublishingYear, Price, EnterDate, CatID, RackID, Amount) VALUES('" & txtBookCode.Text & "','" & txtTitle.Text & "','" & txtAuthor.Text & "','" & txtPublishYear.Text & "','" & txtPrice.Text & "', #" & txtEnterDate.Text & "#, " & txtCategory.Text & "," & txtRack.Text & "," & txtAmount.Text & ")", MyConnection)
   ```
2. **Connection Handling** - You also need to remove `MyConnection.Open' from your Load Handler. Just open it and close it in your Click Handler, as you are currently doing. *This is not causing the error.*
3. **Parameterized SQL** - You need to utilize SQL Parameters, despite the fact that you are not using a Stored Procedure. *This is not the cause of your error*. As [Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119477/conrad-frix) reminded me, your original code dumps values straight from the user into a SQL Statement. Malicious users will steal your data unless you use SQL Parameters.

   ```
   Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("Select * from MyTable where BookID = @BookID")
   CMD.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TXT_BookdID.Text)
   ```

Comment: Lets just hope little bobby tables doesn't author any books that end up in this db

Comment: Are you against the concept of a rapidly user-enhanced evolving database?

Comment: ah its a feature not a defect. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx) property on the command:

```
myCommand.Connection = myConnection
```

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much what the error message implies - the Connection property of the SqlCommand object hasn't been assigned to the connection you opened (in this case you called it `myConnection`).

Also, a word of advice here. Do some reading on sql parameters - doing sql concatenation from user input without any sanity checks is the way [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks happen.

This is one way to do it:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click
    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand( _
        "INSERT INTO tblBook(BookCode, BookTitle, Author, PublishingYear, Price, " & _
        "                    EnterDate, CatID, RackID, Amount) " & _
        "VALUES(@bookCode, @bookTitle, @author, @publishingYear, @price, @enterDate, " & _
        "       @catId, @rackId, @amount)")
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection
        with myCommand.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("bookCode", txtBookCode.Text)
            .AddWithValue("bookTitle", txtTitle.Text)
            .AddWithValue("author", txtAuthor.Text)
            .AddWithValue("publishingYear", txtPublishYear.Text)
            .AddWithValue("price", txtPrice.Text)
            .AddWithValue("enterDate", txtEnterDate.Text)
            .AddWithValue("catId", txtCategory.Text)
            .AddWithValue("rackId", txtRack.Text)
            .AddWithValue("amount", txtAmount.Text)
        end with
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("The book named '" & txtTitle.Text & "' has been inseted successfully")
        ClearBox()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message())
    End Try
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to add "@" to the front of the parameter names in the calls to AddWithValue

Comment: A community comment at the bottom of the MSDN page on [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) claimed it wasn't necessary. I didn't compile and test the above, so, YMMV.

Comment: I checked and you're right you don't need to add the "@" Nice I learned something new. +1

Answer (score 0):

Module Module1
    Public con As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Public com As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Public ds As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim sqlstr As String

```
Public Sub main()
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.....;Initial Catalog=.....;Integrated Security=True;")
    con.Open()
    frmopen.Show()
    'sqlstr = "select * from name1"
    'com = New SqlCommand(sqlstr, con)
    Try
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'MsgBox("success", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message())
    End Try
    'con.Close()



    'MsgBox("ok", MsgBoxStyle.Information, )

End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0):

Please try to wrap the use of your connections (including just opening) inside a USING block. Assuming the use of web.config for connection strings:

```
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("web.config_connectionstring").ConnectionString)
    Dim query As New String = "select * from Table1"
    Dim command as New SqlCommand(query, connection)

Using connection
   connection.Open()
   command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

And PARAMETERIZE anything user-entered.. please!