# INSERT INTO syntax error when saving another file

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using OLE db connection for a payroll system in vb. at first save of a transaction it will successfully save on the database but when i get back to pick another account to compute for its wage and try to save it,it will return an error saying there is a "syntax error on insert into".

here is my code:

```
    com5 = "INSERT INTO PayrollReport Values('" & empno.Text & "','" & ename.Text & "','" & startdate.Text & "','" & _
        cutdate.Text & "'," & bpay.Text & "," & computation.Text & "," & grosse.Text & "," & _
        lwop.Text & "," & tardiness.Text & "," & tax.Text & "," & sssp.Text & "," & _
        philp.Text & "," & hdmfp.Text & "," & sssl.Text & "," & hdmfl.Text & "," & _
        advance.Text & "," & taxdue.Text & "," & nete.Text & "," & deduction.Text & "," & _
        netpay.Text & "," & Employee.Esss.Text & "," & Employee.Ephil.Text & "," & Employee.Ehdmf.Text & ")"


    MsgBox(" The " & ename.Text & "'s Record has been save!")

    connect5()
```

Hope you'll help me with this please...

Comment: what is data type for column number 5 (bpay.Text) ? can you post your table structure?

Comment: What kind of database is this?

Comment: **SQL Injection alert!** - start using **parametrized queries!**

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your code to use what I mention below, your error will become apparent.

You really need to use code like the following to insert data into the database.

**Parameterized SQL** - You need to utilize SQL Parameters, despite the fact that you are not using a Stored Procedure. *This is not the cause of your error*. Your original code dumps values straight from the user into a SQL Statement. Malicious users will steal your data unless you use SQL Parameters.

```
    Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("Select * from MyTable where BookID = @BookID")
    CMD.Parameters.Add("@BookID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TXT_BookdID.Text)
```

Note that not only can you establish placeholders to feed data safely into your database, but you can also establish the data type. This can help catch data-conversion errors. Example, if a user types 4E into a field that is expecting an integer, the code that I posted will give you a very explicit error about failure to convert to int.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360181/127880)

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6003451/127880) will provide you more detail on the proper way to connect to a database in VB.NET.