# Splitting listviews items help needed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, listview

I have some code that loops through a listview and puts the values into 'output1' & 'output2'. However, what is happening is that the results are strung together like thus: 0307NG77775660NG7778. How do I split so that I can include in access db.

There are 2 columns in the listview and they contain values in the format of:

1st row 0307 - NG7777, 2nd row 5660 - 7778 etc. This is a desktop winforms code. Thanks

```
        Dim BoxList As New List(Of String)
        Dim BoxItem As String
        Dim CustRefList As New List(Of String)
        Dim CustRef As String

        For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.lvSelectedItems.Items
            Dim box As String = item.Text
            BoxItem = item.SubItems.Item(1).Text
            BoxList.Add(box)
            output2 += BoxItem

            Dim cust As String = item.Text
            CustRef = item.SubItems.Item(1).Text
            CustRefList.Add(cust)
            output1 += CustRef
        Next

        output = String.Join(" "c, BoxList.ToArray(), CustRefList.ToArray())

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert into Temp (temp, [class]) Values ('" & output1 & "', '" & output2 & "')", oledbCnn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: What output do you want? Please show an example

Comment: it *sounds like* instead of `output1 += username` what you want is to add or update a database with those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make username a `List(Of String)`, then just do:

```
usernameList.Add(username) 'instead of output1 += username
```

When done with the loop, do this:

```
output1 = String.Join(" "c, usernameList.ToArray())
```

You can pick a join character of your choice (if you don't like spaces `" "`).

**EDIT:** Example:

```
Dim usernameList As New List(Of String)
Dim session As String

For Each item As ListViewItem In Me.lvSelectedItems.Items
  Dim username As String = item.Text
  session = item.SubItems.Item(1).Text
  usernameList.Add(username)
  output2 += session
Next

output1 = String.Join(" "c, usernameList.ToArray())
```

Comment: Neolisk I am quite new to vb.net and not advanced enough yet to code what you suggested. Would you have an example you could post please. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468: See my example. I converted `userName`, you can do `session` for learning purposes.

Comment: Many thanks. Just one question, would session be in the same for each as username or a new one. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468: Same ForEach is fine.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. If I have any problems I shall repost.

Comment: Neolisk it errors with 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' which is occuring here: usernameList.Add(username)

Comment: @user1532468: I am sorry, there was a typo - it should have been `New List(Of String)`. I fixed it just now.

Comment: Neolisk. Please look at my amended code. It isn't doing what I thought it would do. It is grouping all the values for each list in a single line. for example, NG565 77889. I need these to be separate for inclusion in db. The user also has the ability to select multiple files, so I don't think this is correct. What is the correct way? Thanks

Comment: @user1532468: Don't Join then. Just use a List you have.

Comment: Neolisk. Are you meaning output =output1 + output2. Thanks

Comment: Neolisk, I am not grasping this. I am getting same item in each output1 and output2. Do I need to change the ite, text somewhere. Thanks

Comment: I have to go out now, but I shall check for any updates in the morning. Many thanks for your patience.

Comment: @user1532468: ExecuteReader is meant for reading. To update, you need [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx). Check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360153/vb-net-sql-server-insert-executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-ini). Basically, loop through your lists, and issue INSERT statement for each. `For i = 0 To list.Count` etc. - assuming both counts are the same, you should be able to do use `list1(i)` and `list2(i)`. Notice use of parameters on the link I mentioned.

Comment: Neolisk, do I loop through the lists in the for each loop and execute sqk there or is that incorrect. thanks

Comment: @user1532468: That would be two loops for you. I'm suggesting one loop, using index variable, to access both of your lists in one loop. The rest is okay.